# working with virtual network interfaces on the existing wlan0 interface

Tags: wifi

**Scenario**:
In a nut-shell I am trying to use the existing `wlan0` interface on my system, create two virtual interfaces on top of it and use one of them as an access point and the other one as a normal WiFi client.

**Problem**:
I am able to create the virtual interfaces, see them using `iwconfig` but only one of them can be brought up using `ifconfig`. If I try to bring up the other interface I get

```
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Device or resource busy.
```

**Hardware details**:
Xilinx SoC (ARM processor)
Petalinux (Linux Distro)
Intel 8265 NGW (WiFi chipset)

I am quite sure that the Intel hardware supports three modes simultaneously this is the output of `iw list | grep -A 2 'interface combination'`:

```
valid interface combinations:
                 * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ AP, P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1, total <= 3, #channels <= 2
```

This is what I am doing on the terminal:

```
iw dev wlan0 interface add vwlan0 type managed
iw dev wlan0 interface add vwlan1 type managed
```

Output of `iwconfig`

```
vwlan0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm  
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off  
          Encryption key:off  
          Power Management:on  

vwlan1    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm  
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off  
          Encryption key:off  
          Power Management:on  

sit0      no wireless extensions.  

lo        no wireless extensions.  

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  Mode:Master  Tx-Power=22 dBm  
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off  
          Power Management:on  

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

`ifconfig vwlan0 up` works but
`ifconfig vwlan1 up` gives
`ifconfig: SIOCSIFFLAGS: Device or resource busy`

Answer (score 1):

I found out by chance that I do not have to bring up the virtual interface I created.

#### Example

If I execute this statement:

```
$ iw dev wlan0 interface add vwlan0 type managed
```

It creates a virtual interface `vwlan0` and I can use either `hostapd` or `wpa_supplicant` to use it as an access point or WiFi client directly without executing:

```
$ ifconfig vwlan0 up
```

I have to make sure that `wlan0` is up and it does the trick.